# Error while submiting a form in my react application

Tags: reactjs

I got an error while a form it says "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): err.response is undefined"

here is the code in which error is occouring

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {setAlert} from "./alert";
import {ADD_JOB, DELETE_JOB, GET_JOBS, JOB_ERROR, UPDATE_APPLY,GET_JOB} from "./types";

//Add job

export const addJob = (companyname, jobtitle, address, jobdetail,website) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify({companyname, jobtitle, address, jobdetail,website});

    try {
        const res = await axios.post("api/jobs", body , config);

        dispatch({
            type: ADD_JOB,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(setAlert('Job Posted', 'success'));
    }catch (err) {
        const error = err.response.data.error;

        if (error) {
            error.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
        }
        dispatch({
            type: JOB_ERROR,
            payload: {msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
        });
    }
};
```

it says err.reponse is udefined

Comment: Check what is the value of the error on the first line of the catch block, that is where the exception is coming from.

Comment: yes if possbile just log value of err in 1st line of catch block, it will be helpful for us to debug it and help you out.

Comment: thank you both of you for giving me this idea